Cannot write the token [webform_submission:url] to a webform field
I have a form where images amongst other things are submitted.  I need to be able to relate back to the original webform submission where they were submitted in a Drupal View (that is not based on Webform submissions themselves) and so I created a hidden field to store the submission url on the webform itself but it does not get written.  I know I can use [webform_submission:url] on the confirmation screen and emails.
I've tried using [webform_submission:token-view-url] but this causes an error on saving that element with respect to rendering the route.  The update token, [webform_submission:token-view-url] will save without error and does save but does not give a usable URL.
I assume this is a 'timing thing' where the webform submission does not actually complete and get this information until it is saved etc.  Is there a way to do this easily?

I had to resort to writing a custom Webform Handler to get this to work properly. There are plenty of resources to get you started on doing this, I used the Webform Example Handler code (webform_example_handler) from the Webform module, but if anyone wants the full code, just shout.
I added a webform element of type URL to store the update link. I then created a custom submitForm function to write the update URL to this element:
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission)
{
    //$this->debug(__FUNCTION__);
    
    if ($webform_submission->isNew()) {// a new submission
        $values = $form_state->getValues();
        // I do other things for my form here...
       // Now write the update URL to my URL element directly into the submission data
       $updateURL = $webform_submission->getTokenUrl('update')->toString();//getTokenUrl is from the WebformSubmission.php
       $webform_submission->setElementData('update_webform_url', $updateURL);
    }
}

I hope this helps others
